# Is $\lim_{x \to x_0} \log(f(x)) = \log\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)$ always true?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, logarithms

This property is always true? If yes I would like a proof, otherwise an counterexample.

$$\lim\limits_{x \to x_0} \log(f(x)) = \log\lim\limits_{x \to x_0} f(x)$$

Comment: This might be helpful: http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/courses/185F08/composition.pdf

Comment: This is true since $\log(\cdot)$ is continuous and provided $f(x) > 0$ in a neighborhood of $x_0$ and $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) > 0$.

Comment: On the other hand, in the complex numbers no branch of log can be continuous on ${\mathbb C} \backslash \{0\}$, and then it is possible to have $\lim_{z \to z_0} \log f(z) \ne \log \lim_{z \to z_0} f(z)$.

Answer (score 3):

This property is always true because $\log$ is a continuous function.

Comment: All right, So this property it's true for each continuous function. Thanks :-)

Comment: When you say log is a continuous function, you should probably mention what domain you mean.